# How can I keep the state of editor-fold in Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1?

Tags: android-studio

I use the latest Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1.

I can use the following code to collapse or expand a a section code.

It seems that Android Studio can't keep the state of `editor-fold`, for example, I have collapsed the section code, but sometimes it is expanded automatically in Android Studio.

How can I keep the state of `editor-fold` ? You know I will write code in different PC and sync project with GitHub.

```
//<editor-fold desc="Paint">
//----------------------------- Paint ---------------------------------------------


val paintDial = Paint().also {
    it.isAntiAlias = true
    it.style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
    it.strokeWidth = 3f
    it.color = Color.Red
}

val paintText = TextPaint().also {
    it.isAntiAlias = true
    it.color = Color.Red.toArgb()
    it.textSize = 30f
}


//----------------------------- Paint ---------------------------------------------
//</editor-fold>
```

And more, I have read the [article](https://medium.com/android-news/create-regions-in-android-studio-55333a1ad8a1), It seems that I can use the following code to collapse or expand a a section code.

The same question: can I save the state of collapse or expand with `region` ?  You know I will write code in different PC and sync project with GitHub.

```
//region Helper method

    //do your work here

//endregion
```

BTW, in my mind, Microsoft Visual Studio can use the following code to save the state of collapse or expand.

```
/* #region Main */
public static void Main(string args[])
{
   //Your code goes here
}
/* #endregion */
```

Comment: IDEA also support VS code-folding comments, just not both in the same source file: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/

Comment: Thanks! I need to save the state of collapse or expand  in different PCs via GitHub.

Comment: The documentation is not really clear about it, but the state may be stored in IDE caches.

Comment: Android studio is based on intellij-community version. One idea is to clone from github the relevant version of intellij, run it with debugger and debug where it writes the state of `folding` code

Comment: Another idea is to sniff all the changes of all cache dirs of android studio with any file watcher, for example `git` is a great tool for that